# Operator function, comparing two datatypes

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to create an operator function that takes one integer and one double as parameters and returns true if the integer is lesser than the double, else it will return false.
I came from a programming language named Ada, where such tasks would be executed in this manner but doesn't seem to be the same with C++.

Is it possible to do this in C++ and if so what's really wrong with my code?

This is the errors I get:

```
12 | bool operator <(int const lhs,
      |      ^~~~~~~~
```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool operator <(int const lhs,
                double const rhs)
{
    if (double(lhs) < rhs)
    {
    return true;
    }
    
return false;

}

int main()
{
    int lhs {};
    double rhs {};
 
    
    cin >> lhs >> rhs;
    
      
    if (!rhs < lhs)
    {
        cout << "False";
    }
    
}
```

In my main program I tried outputting "False" if `rhs < lhs = false`

Comment: `cin >> lhs >> rhs;` ?

Comment: In C++, overloading of operator functions requires at least one of their arguments to be a user-defined type.    It is not possible to overload a binary operator function with both arguments as basic types (like `int`, `float`, etc).   The design rationale for this is to prevent the language from being mutable (e.g. it is not possible to change the meaning of comparing a `float` and an `int` from what is built into the language, so [say] the expression `a < b` gives a true result if `a > b`).

Comment: `cin >> lhs > rhs;` is interpreted as `(cin>>lhs) > rhs;` and since the `>>` operator taking references to `std::istream` and `int` returns a reference to the `std::istream` the following code would yield the same result: `std::cin >> lhs; std::cin > rhs;` but as the compiler told you there's no `>` operator applicable here...

Comment: That was a typo on in my part. I updated my question and updated my error messages.  I only get one error message and it doens't give me a lot of info...

Comment: Since neither parameter is a user defined type, you cannot do `operator<`, you'll need to write your own `bool is_less(int const lhs, double const rhs)` function.  Did you intend to call using `(double, int)` for a function that takes `(int, double)`?  The compiler will do implicit conversion.  Coming from Ada, you may find C++ to be a bit more wild wild west.

Comment: @Eljay Ok so I guess we can only use operators for classes, structures, pointers etc?

It's weird because my teacher gave an example of how a C++ operator could look like but I guess it's wrong?

He gave the following example:


`string operator* (string const & lhs, int const rhs)
{
...

}`

Comment: A `string` is a user defined type.  Overloading operators for standard library types (which are user defined types) is probably frowned upon by the C++ standard.

Answer (score 0):

You may overload operators for user-defined types as for example classes or enumerations.

As for this statement

```
cin >> lhs > rhs;
```

then due to the operator precedence it is equivalent to

```
( cin >> lhs ) > rhs;
```

So in fact you are trying to compare an object of the type std::istream with an object of the type double. But such an operator is not defined.

Also it seems in the condition of the if statement

```
if (!rhs < lhs)
```

there is a typo.

Maybe you mean

```
if (!( rhs < lhs ) )
```

Comment: That was a typo on in my part. I updated my question and updated my error messages.  I only get one error message and it doens't give me a lot of info...

Comment: @MohamedAlkalam It does not matter. I already have answered your question that you may not overload the operator for non-user defined types.

Comment: But I am converting my integer in my function to a double so in that case I am comparing a double with a double.

Comment: Even if I compare to integers, it won't work.

Comment: @MohamedAlkalam  You may not overload operators for non-user defined types. What is unclear?

Comment: Ok so I guess we can only use operators for classes, structures, pointers etc?

It's weird because my teacher gave an example of how a C++ operator could look like but I guess it's wrong?

He gave the following example:


`string operator* (string const & lhs, int const rhs)
{
...

}`

Comment: @MohamedAlkalam The type string is a user defined type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240536/discussion-between-mohamed-alkalam-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: @MohamedAlkalam I am sorry but a have no time to discuss this question because all is clear written in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant `lhs < rhs`, rather than `rhs < lhs`, you'll need to provide a function for the less comparison, rather than try to overload the `operator<` with non-user defined types.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;

// Thwart implicit conversion.
template <typename T, typename T2>
bool is_less(T const, T2 const) = delete;

template <>
bool is_less(int const lhs,
             double const rhs)
{
    if (double(lhs) < rhs)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    int lhs {};
    double rhs {};

    cin >> lhs >> rhs;

    // Note: changed (rhs, lhs) to (lhs, rhs).
    if (!is_less(lhs, rhs))
    {
        cout << "False\n";
    }
}
```